# Lightspeed Connector for Magento - How to disable Description updates from Lightspeed so they are only managed in Magento?

Tags: magento, connector, lightspeed

Lightspeed Retail Connector for Magento - How to disable Description updates from Lightspeed so they are only managed in Magento? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Lightspeed seems to update the descriptions randomly. We've lost once all our descriptions once because we kept the web descriptions fields empty and managed it from magento instead of LS. The solution for that was to use store views. Lightspeed will only ever update the default store view, and that was easy for us since our website is in both french and english and we had to change store views all the time anyway. Now we change the name of products and their descriptions in the FR and EN store views and leave the default alone.

But it is strange how lightspeed updates the descriptions. It seems random